# Refactoring code to a generic method - String.format

Tags: java, string, format

Considering this code:

```
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %50s %n", "|", "Date: " + DATE.format(this.getDate()))); // HEADER
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %50s %n", "|", "Place: " + this.place())); // HEADER

    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %n", "|")); // SEPARATOR

    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %s %n", "|", "Place description")); // CONTENT HEADER
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %n", "|")); // SEPARATOR
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", "Elevation", "Latitude", "Longitude)); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", "---------", "---------", "---------")); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION

    for(Place p : placeList)
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", p.getElevation(), p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude));

    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %n", "|")); // SEPARATOR

    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %s %n", "|", "Place dimension")); // CONTENT HEADER
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %n", "|")); // SEPARATOR

    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", "X", "Y", "Z", "Points")); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", "---------", "---------", "---------", "---------")); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION

    for(Dimension d : dimensionList)
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", d.getX(), o.getY(), o.getZ(), o.getPoints()));
```

Currently with this code I generate a report to a text file.

So far I managed to refactor here:

```
public static StringBuilder buildText(  StringBuilder stringBuilder, 
                                        ReportPart reportPart,
                                        Object... content){

    String separatorPattern = "'%s %n', '|'";

    switch (reportPart) {
        case HEADER:
            String headerPattern = "%s %50s %n";                

            stringBuilder.append(String.format(headerPattern, "|", "Date: " + content[0]));
            stringBuilder.append(String.format(headerPattern, "|", "Place: " + content[1]));

            stringBuilder.append(String.format(separatorPattern));

            break;

        case CONTENT_HEADER:
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %s %n", "|", content[0]));

            stringBuilder.append(String.format(separatorPattern));

            break;

        case CONTENT_DESCRIPTION:

            break;
    }
```

And i use just like this:

```
    buildText(sb, ReportPart.HEADER, this.getDate(), this.getPlace()));
    buildText(sb, ReportPart.CONTENT_HEADER, "Place description");
```

But, as you can see, my 'CONTENT_DESCRIPTION' has a variable size, and with that I need to also change the method of string formatting.

I do not know how I can do this, can someone help me?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're only having trouble with a couple of those lines, it's best to try to show us a *small* program with those lines. The more code that you give, the harder it is for anyone to wade through all of the code to help, so it makes sense to have just enough code to show what you're asking, and no more. It'll also make it easier to come back to this question later if you ever have a similar problem later on down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advange of the varargs parameter of the String.format() and pass a String array.

```
 stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", "X", "Y", "Z", "Points")); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION
 stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", "---------", "---------", "---------", "---------")); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION
```

AND

```
stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "|", "Elevation", "Latitude", "Longitude)); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION
stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n","|", "---------", "---------", "---------")); // <- My problems here - CONTENT DESCRIPTION
```

Can become something like:

```
String[] parameters = {"|","X","Y","Z","Points"}; // OR {"|", "Elevation", "Latitude", "Longitude"};

StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder("%s ");
for(int i = 1; i < parameters.length; i++){
    pattern.append("%-15s ");
}
pattern.append("%n");

List<String> divider = new ArrayList<String>();
divider.add("|");
for(int i = 1; i < parameters.length; i++){
    divider.add("---------");
}
stringBuilder.append(String.format(pattern.toString(), parameters));
stringBuilder.append(String.format(pattern.toString(), divider.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Maybe have something to check the size of the parameters array to multiply the "----------" string, but i didnt know how to do that. sorry :). Hope this helps.

edit: added something to add dividers depending on number of parameters.

edit 2: pattern adjusted depending on number of parameters.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

I thought about doing that way, but every time I have to manually adjust the pattern.

I'm trying to make it as generic as possible.

Comment: check the edit :) maybe that helps